# Parse input into blocks enclosed in curly braces with Sed

Tags: regex, awk, sed

Two files:

File 1

```
{
foo
}
{
bar
}
```

File 2

```
foo
}
{
bar
}
```

(Only difference is file 1 starts with open curly brace)

The following expression works on file 2, but not file 1, why? (And how to fix?):

```
sed '1!N; s/}\n{/},\n{/' < file1 or file2
```

I don't know why the open curly brace, 2 lines before a match, would cause this behavior. I'd like to know the reason why sed is getting tripped up and how to fix it. But I'm also open to other ways to insert a `,` between `}\n{` besides sed.

Comment: You haven't told us what it means for a script to "work". Please edit your question to show the expected output for both files.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want (uses GNU awk for multi-char RS):

```
$ awk -v RS='}\n{' '{ORS=(RT?"},\n{":"")} 1' file1
{
foo
},
{
bar
}

$ awk -v RS='}\n{' '{ORS=(RT?"},\n{":"")} 1' file2
foo
},
{
bar
}
```

Comment: Nicely done; to perhaps help others understand: GNU Awk's (non-standard) `RT` variable reflects the actual match for `RS` encountered as the terminator (separator) for the record at hand.
With the OP's input, `RT` will be _empty_ for the _last_ record, which allows dynamically setting `ORS` to an empty string for the last record, so that the `},\n{` sequence is effectively only inserted _between_ records.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't the opening brace, it is the extra line. Put *anything* on that line (even nothing) and your script stops working.

Your script is *strictly* pair-based. It only works when the closing `}` falls on an *even* line.

Your Sed script says `1!N` - for every line that isn't the first line, read the *next* line into the pattern space, then attempt the `s///` transformation.

Then the end of the script happens, and Sed prints the pattern space, discards it, and reads the next line. You only ever pair up two lines at once, starting from the second line.

A file of

```
}
{
```

wouldn't get modified correctly either, but

```
f
}
{
```

will.

This Sed command

```
sed '/}$/{N;s/}\n{/},\n{/}'
```

will work for files that don't contain `}\n}\n{` (it'll miss those).

For something more robust you either need something like `awk` or someone better at `sed` than I am to come up with a smarter script.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed '1b;$!N; s/}\n{/},\n{/;P;D' file
```

Currently you are processing pairs of lines after the first what you want is to traverse the file using a window of two lines.
This will bump the two line window one further line at a time to the end of the file i.e. it deletes the first line but retains the second then appends the next line to that line. To see how it works (and useful for all sed scripts in general) use the `l` command as so:

```
sed '1b;$!N;l;s/}\n{/},\n{/;P;D' file
```

Comment: That sliding-window technique is great. Here is a simpler GNU Sed command using `l` that helped me understand it: `sed '$!N; l; D' <<<$'line 1\nline 2\nline 3\nline 4\nline 5'` (sadly, only GNU Sed visualizes pattern space-internal newlines as `\n` - it's less helpful with BSD Sed).
I suggest using `$!N` in general, to ensure that the last line is fully processed as well (GNU Sed, when `N` is called on the last line, will still _print_ it, but will skip the remaining commands in the script; BSD Sed, in accordance with POSIX, will not even print it).

Comment: Here's a (tweaked) version of the command that also works with BSD/OSX Sed (assumes Bash, Ksh, or Zsh): `sed $'$!N; s/}\\n{/},\\\n{/; P; D' file`

Comment: @mklement0 amended to cater for last line processing

Answer (score 1):

[Etan Reisner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33161520/45375) explains the problem with your `sed` command well.

Generally, `awk` makes it easier to deal with parsing that *spans lines*.

Assuming *GNU* `awk` or `mawk`, try the following:

```
awk -v RS='\n}\n{' '/\}\n$/ { printf "%s", $0; next; } { printf "%s\n},\n{", $0 }' file
```

Nested `{...}` sequences inside the top-level ones are OK, as long as their closing `}` is *indented*.

- `RS='\n}\n{'` means that the input is broken into records - across lines - by `\n}\n{` sequences.

  - **Note**: Multi-characters `RS` values are an *extension* to the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html), which GNU Awk and Mawk happen to implement; BSD Awk, as also used on OS X, does *not*.
- `/\}\n$/` matches only the *last* record, because it isn't followed by another `{`:

  - `printf "%s", $0` simply prints it as-is; its opening `{`, if any, was printed in the context of the previous record, if any.
- Otherwise - the 1st or any interior record - is printed with a `,` inserted between its closing `}` and the next record's opening `{`: `{ printf "%s\n},\n{", $0 }`